# How to use the Graph API to show the user his facebook friends that have already signed up for my site

Tags: php, facebook, foursquare, facebook-graph-api

I am looking at the Graph API .. and how to get a persons friends, apparently its only returning the name and the ID of the friend, I don't know how to go about this, I need something like email to show them that these friends are already signed up for my site....

Sorta like what foursquare does

Comment: I recently signed up for Foursquare, what they do is it lets you connect to facebook, then it tells you what friends on your facebook already have Foursquare accounts.

How can I achieve the same thing? I tried the 

https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=....

It only gave back name and id ... there has to be another way

Comment: You're wanting to query the user's friends to see which are already registered to your service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you're keeping track of the friends in your application, if you just store their facebook id along with other info in your application then getting the friend list without any more parameters is enough as it returns id and name by default:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=AUTH_TOKEN
```

returns:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Friend1",
         "id": "123456"
      }
   ]
}
```

If you aren't keeping track of any facebook info in your application and you want to compare based in some other field you would add the fields parameter and specify the field you want to search on:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=AUTH_TOKEN&fields=name,picture
```

returns:

```
{
       "data": [
          {
             "name": "Friend1",
             "id": "123456",
             "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak/blalala"                 
          }
    ]
}
```

- id is always returned even if you don't specify it in the fields params.
- email requires extended permissions to be granted once the user adds your application, and is not an option from the friend's list...

The full list of selectors/fields is here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user

Answer (score 1):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions - friends email is not an available option.  Presumably if the user has signed up to you via facebook, you could store their facebook ID and then query against that?

Answer (score 0):

Because the user is logged in who's friends list you are going to fetch and off course you have authentication token against logged-in user, use this graph api url to get list in json format.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=AUTH_TOKEN
```

And off course you have extended permissions for that user too.